# Problems to align horizontal forms in Bootstrap 3 on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013, vertical-alignment

This form renders ok in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, in Mac and PC, but in IE 11, I have problem with vertical align of two forms. This is a Sharepoint 2013 site.

My code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">Código*:</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="12" class="form-control" />
            <span  style="display:none;"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">Nome*:</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="150"  class="form-control" />
            <span style="display:none;"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix it?

[My form with the problem in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoRFg.gif)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Have you tried inspecting the element to understand what property is causing the unwanted behavior?

Comment: I know the code is correct. The problem is the browser IE, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure IE 11's Compatibility Mode is not turned on for the URL you are looking at.